# SonarQube Redmine Integration

Tags: sonarqube5.2

Scenario is After Installing Plugin with SonarQube

Error is Missing parameter resource

While integrating Sonar with Redmine, At Project level, go to Administration -> Redmine Configuration Page is not loading, Instead of that am getting the above error message on browser.

I am using following versions,
Maven  3.0.5
Redmine version  3.0.4.stable
SonarQube        5.2

Regards,
Jojan Paul

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug on the plugin. I have found a workaround until this is fixed. In your browser, you need to replace the url GET paramater 'id' by 'resource'.

So insterad of

```
http://{sonar_url}/redmine_configuration?id={project}
```

Replace 'id' with 'resource'

```
http://{sonar_url}/redmine_configuration?resource={project}
```