# SonarQube Redmine plugin connection error

Tags: sonarqube, redmine, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.1.2

I try to connect SonarQube to Redmine.
SonarQube v.5.1.2
Redmine v.3.1.2

I connected to Redmine server using API key, Project key and Redmine URL successfully.

Then I opened "Issue" in SonarQube and clicked on "More"->"Link to Redmine".
After that I had an error:

Impossible to create an issue on Redmine. A problem occurred with the remote server:Project cannot be blank.

What does it mean? But I have not blank project in Redmine.
What i`m doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for you answer, Guillaume.
Everything on my settings configured correctly and connection works fine.

Finally, I found a solution!

1. I went to: https://your_redmine_url/projects/name_of_project/issues.xml
   There I can see "project id" and "project name".
   But before, I used project name (identifier on redmine project settings).
2. I changed "project key" (on sonarqube) from "project name" (example: my_project) to "project id" (example: 12). This field "12" you can see on issues.xml.

And it works! I created an issue on Redmine! There was a problem - in project id field.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin is not up to date.

I think the way to overcome this error should be to configure your redmine project in the specific dashboard you want to link redmine to.

Check my answer here: 
[SonarQube Redmine Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081055/sonarqube-redmine-integration/34232372#34232372)

Once you are on your sonar specific redmine configuration, make sure you update the "Project > Project key" using the redmine project "identifier" field, which is the slug of your project.

You can hit 'connect' to make sure its working. Then don't forget to hit the very bottom button 'save settings'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found solution. The problem was in project id (I used project name).